# How to get markers associated with a specific model?

Tags: vue.js, monaco-editor

According to the official document, the API `getModelMarkers` receives owner, resource and take as filters. What I want to do is to get markers associated with a specific model directly.

I saw someone use getModelMarkers(model.id) somewhere, and I have tried. Although it returned markers, I found it behaved weird: it returned the same result after I changed the model...

So, did I do it in a wrong way? or We just can't get markers according to a model?

If you need more information, let me know. Thanks.